# How do i Add callBack Functionality to my hubClass in signalR for update the current work status to client with time delay?

Tags: javascript, c#, server, client, signalr

I  am  new to signalR.I  am developing a  simple application in signalR. The Requirement is ,the signalR need to be update the current time to client repeatedly with some time delay.While i am starts running, the code i get server response for a time only.it's not repeated again and again. i  need to callback the sameHubclass for update the current time to client again and again!

here is my Code:-

Javascript Client Code:-

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<input type="hidden" id="name" />
</div>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        var chat = $.connection.timeHub;
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name,current) {
        var now = current;
        console.log(current);
        $('div.container').append('<p><strong>'+name+"=" 
               + now + '</strong></p>');

        };
        $("#name").val(prompt("Enter the UserName", ""));

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                chat.server.send($("#name").val());

            });

    });
</script>
</body>
```

HubClass:-

```
public class timeHub : Hub
{
   public void send(string name)
    {

        while(true)
        {

            string current = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:tt");
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name,current);
            Console.WriteLine(current);
            Console.ReadLine();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            send(name);
        }
    }
}
```

MyOwin Startup Class:-

```
 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Time.Startup))]

 namespace Time
  {
    public class Startup
     {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {
           app.MapSignalR();
         }
     }
 }
```

How do i add callback functionality for my HubClass in  Javascript Client Code in SignalR.

here is my current Output without callback function and timedelay:-

[image: It update the current Client in time only]

but the signalR and .net client application or working fine.I need to time delay for hubclass and callback the samehub class periodically?

[image: Here another output]

Is it possible to callback the same hub class in server with some time delay?
For that i am added, time delay in hubclass. and i callback the hubclass in server .It won't work.Could anyone provide me an solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use a timer that calls the broadcastMessage method with the current time. There are some issues with your `send` hub method though.  Also SignalR instantiates the hub class per each call and state is not maintained.

Comment: Thanks hex. For this i am added a timer inside the Hub Class. and set the loop with recursive functions.Now the solution works.

Comment: @G.Thirunavukkarasu You should actually broadcast the time to clients from outside the hub.  On the server, create a class in which you have the hubcontext. a timer and a delegate method for the timer.  The method will get the current time and use the hubcontext to call the broadcastMessage.  You shouldn't set the timer/loop inside the hub class.  Check this MSDN link where they go over this topic in detail: https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub

Comment: fine hex.I will go through it.